# How to calculate precision and recall from classification report

Tags: python

I have a classification report like:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Output:

```
    precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       1.00      1.00      1.00        15
         1.0       1.00      0.95      0.98        22
         2.0       0.93      1.00      0.96        13

    accuracy                           0.98        50
   macro avg       0.98      0.98      0.98        50
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98        50
```

How to get precision and recall from it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at their library?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Precision and recall are well documented in many places, including code examples.  We expect you to research before posting here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **precision_recall_fscore_support()** function.

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
```

For more details please refer the documentation [1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html) precision_recall_fscore_support :